# Flash message shows twice in a view CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, flash-message

I've encountered this issue several times and tried to avoid it by removing calling Flash method. Lately, I want to show an error flash to non-logged in user who tries to log out. However, when I test this action(by accessing localhost:8765/users/logout without being logged in), everything works fine except I get 2 error messages "You are not authorized to access this location". How can I fix this issue?

Here are my codes

In AppController:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],  //For User authorize checking, this tells app to let each controller decides own rules for authorize
       'loginRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index'],
       'logoutRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']
    ]);
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    //this applied to every controller
    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display']);
}

  ...

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    //Admin can access every action
    if(isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin'){
        return true;
    }

    //Default deny
    return false;
}
```

In UsersController:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    //All registered users can add articles
    if($this->request->action === 'add'){
        return true;
    }

    //The self user can edit and delete the account
    if(in_array($this->request->action, ['edit', 'delete'])){            
        //get id of targeted user
        $targetUserId = (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0];
        //check if current user is the targeted user
        if($this->Users->selfUser($targetUserId, $user['id'])){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('You are not authorized for this action'));
        }
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['add']);
}

...

public function logout()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

In UsersTable

```
public function selfUser($targetedUserId, $userId)
{

    return $targetedUserId == $userId;
}
```

In default.ctp

```
$cakeDescription = 'CakePHP: the rapid development php framework';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        <?= $cakeDescription ?>:
        <?= $this->fetch('title') ?>
    </title>
    <?= $this->Html->meta('icon') ?>

    <?= $this->Html->css('base.css') ?>
    <?= $this->Html->css('cake.css') ?>

    <?= $this->fetch('meta') ?>
    <?= $this->fetch('css') ?>
    <?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="top-bar expanded" data-topbar role="navigation">
        <ul class="title-area large-3 medium-4 columns">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href=""><?= $this->fetch('title') ?></a></h1>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/">Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/">API</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

In login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your username and password') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you also post even just an excerpt from your CTP file? It could be possible that within the page layout the Flash was rendered twice.

Comment: Can you give me the file name and its directory? Do you mean the default.ctp in Layout folder?

Comment: That actually depends on where you rendered the Flash message. You could try searching for the line: "$this->Flash->render()" in your default.ctp. It could also be in the CTP file for your login screen. Basically, try searching for the line of code I've mentioned and see if it was added twice. It could also be possible that you've added the code to both your default.ctp and to the ctp file for your login itself.

Comment: I saw a $this->Flash->render() in default.ctp. So, when a $this->Flash->error() is executed in UsersController, it also triggers the $this->Flash->render() in default.ctp? Should I delete $this->Flash->render() or somehow modify the $this->Flash->error() in UsersController to fix this issue?

Comment: The line: $this->Flash->render() is basically dictating where your flash message is going to appear. The line: $this->Flash->error() would then provide the contents for the render function to display.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I found the <?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?> in login.ctp. This got to be the issue right.

Comment: So to be clear, you've found the line: '$this->Flash->render()' in 2 different files, right? Try getting rid of one of those lines and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I can't test whether this solution works or not since I'm having problem with login and logout(I don't know what did I mess up but I can't log out despite accessing logout link or even delete the current account(in delete function also calls logout function). I tried to restart xampp, browser, git bash and server. Non of them fix the problem. Anyway, I believe that render line is the problem for flashing twice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line in your logout action:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

So, in your case, your UsersController should be:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    //All registered users can add articles
    if($this->request->action === 'add'){
        return true;
    }

    //The self user can edit and delete the account
    if(in_array($this->request->action, ['edit', 'delete'])){            
        //get id of targeted user
        $targetUserId = (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0];
        //check if current user is the targeted user
        if($this->Users->selfUser($targetUserId, $user['id'])){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('You are not authorized for this action'));
        }
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['add']);
}

...

public function logout()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```